# SQLQuery not returning document queried

Tags: sql, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Azure Function App with Cosmos DB + nodejs not working with SQLQuery (Input). No document returned.

I have successfully gotten an Id/PartionKey combo to return a document. I have tried many combos of SQL queries in the input's SQLQuery field such as from the docs to no avail. No error nor document is returned. I would expect my query to be:

```
SELECT * from Users where Users.UserName = '12345'
```

I have tried with and without a value in single quotes. I've tried hard coded (no binding) queries such as:

```
SELECT * from Users where Users.UserName = 12345
```

And ones with binding (with and without single quotes around {userName}):

```
SELECT * from Users where Users.UserName = {userName}
```

I have tried using {userName} by putting it into the routing:

Account/login/{userName}

and I have also tried using userName from the Query (with or without single quotes):

```
SELECT * from Users where Users.UserName = '{Query.userName}'
```

Partion key is: /id

```
{
    "indexingMode": "consistent",
    "automatic": true,
    "includedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/*"
        }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [
        {
            "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have done many hours of searches and reading and I understand binding may not be supported fully with the SQLQuery, however, even hard coding a value fails to return a document.

Sample document:

```
{
    "id": "e90ece01373e5d011fdaef2c20d9717b",
    "UserName": "17002",
    "password": "newpassword",
    "Address": "123 West ",
    "state": "FL",
    "city":  "mycity",
    "zip": "32222",
    "phoneNumber": "3215551212",
    "emailId": "email@email.com",
    "refNo": "0",
    "aboutUs": "someplace",
    ........
}
```

Function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post",
        "get"
      ],
      "route": "Account/login/{userName}"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "myInput",
      "databaseName": "cdel",
      "collectionName": "Users",
      "connectionStringSetting": "cdel_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM Users where Users.UserName = {userName}"
    }
  ]
}
```

index.js:

```
module.exports = async function (context, req, myInput) {
    context.log('JavaScript queue trigger function processed work item');
    context.log('Passed in: ' + context.bindingData.userName);
    if (!myInput)
    {
        context.log("UserName not found");
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "UserName not found."
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.log(req.query.password);
        context.log(myInput.password);
        context.log(context.bindings.myInput.password);

        if (myInput.password != req.query.password) {
            context.res = {
                status: 400,
                body: "Invalid logon."
            }
        }
        else {
              .....
        }
    }
    context.done();
};
```

Expect single document to be returned. None is returned. myInput.password = undefined

Is there a query monitor of sorts I haven't found so I can see what is happening?

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: Is this nodejs in runtime 2.0 or 1.0?

Comment: This is using nodejs in their portal editor environment. I believe it's 2.0 if FUNCTIONS EXTENSIONS VERSION is it and based on the binding not working (from many threads I've read). That says 2. I'm too new to this environment. Otherwise, where do I find that info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cosmos is returning collection, you need to grab first element from it.

```
context.bindings.myInput[0].password
```

So the code is

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('password: ' + req.body.password);
    if (context.bindings.myInput.length > 0)
        context.log('password cosmos: ' + context.bindings.myInput[0].password);
    context.res = {
        body: "OK"
    };
};
```

Comment: You are awesome. Thank you. The myInput[0] was the key. I'm too new to this and haven't seen an example like that (other than interating in a loop). Case closed!

Comment: Yea, no problem. I misread your question because you suggested the answer in your post by saying it didn't return the document, it did but you didn't refer to it correctly.

Comment: Side note, I would never create my own identity management solution this days, I would either use Azure AD B2B or B2C, storing password is very bad practice.

Comment: Because myInput.password worked when using Id and PartitionKey as the way to get the data, I assumed the myInput.password was valid. It wasn't until someone proved that the data was in fact being retrieved that the problem changed. I will look into the Azure AD. I still needed to get SQL Queries working regardless. Thank you again (spent days reading and researching).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select *
from Users
where UserName = '12345678'
```

Comment: This resulted in an error: Message: {"errors":[{"severity":"Error","location":{"start":26,"end":34},"code":"SC2001","message":"Identifier 'UserName' could not be resolved."}]}
ActivityId: 4cbb01f8-6af3-458e-95e7-13bca1e4f27f, Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/2.5.1, Windows/10.0.14393 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.2.0